# XCtest : how can I simulate a phone call interruption in UItest for ios

Tags: xctest, uitest

I'm looking for a way can simulate an interruption like phone calls when doing xctesting.

Comment: Assuming there is a way, what do you want to check?

Comment: hmmm , want to check if some function goes well when we have a phone call interruption, it's like addUIInterruptionMonitor what this api doing.

Comment: And how does your app change behavior when a phone call comes in?